# How to change the text to the bottom center?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the design I want:
[image]

This is my current design:
[image]

I'm just freaking out. I would like to ask how to make the text in the bottom center position like the design picture I showed. Can anyone help me in solving this problem? I've tried but still can't get the design the way I want. I hope stack overflow can help me.

This is my code:

```dart
Container(
  height: 150,
  width: double.infinity,
  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 3.0))),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 370,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text('Other medical records and vitals',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                /*height: 50,
                                    width: 370,*/
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    width: 1.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Wrap(
                          direction: Axis.vertical,
                          children: [Text('Heart Rate')],
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your `Row` is not in right place and put it in `Column`,

and if you like you can add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround` to your Row too. if space are too close just wrap with `Padding` and set edge only,

Try this code (you can now wrap widget with `Align` and get best result as you like) :

```
Container(
      height: 150,
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 3.0))),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 370,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
            child: const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text('Other medical records and vitals',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black)),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
                Text('Heart Rate'),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text('Heart Rate2'),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text('Heart Rate3'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Just move the `Heart Rate` to the parent `Column` and add an `Align` to move it to the bottom-center.

Check it out:

[image: Screenshot]

The code is going to be the following:

```dart
Container(
    height: 150,
    width: double.infinity,
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 3.0))),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 370,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    width: 1.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text('Other medical records and vitals',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const Spacer(),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
              /*height: 50,
                                    width: 370,*/
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
              child: const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Text('Heart Rate'),
              )),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
    @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ),

        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
              Text('Other medical records and vitals',),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      // Add your code/ Widgets here
                      Text('Heart Rate'),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text('Heart Rate2'),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text('Heart Rate3'),
                    ]
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```